# Freeing data in a linked list

Tags: c, list, memory, struct, free

Hey I am currently working on a tasks where I need to delete specific nodes in a list. I also need to free the memory of those nodes.
This is the given struct:

```c
typedef struct      s_list
{
    struct s_list   *next;
    void            *data;    
}                   t_list;
```

The function I need to create gets passed a function which free's the data of the node.

```c
void remove_node(t_list **begin_list, void (*free_fct)(void *))
//free_fct being the function to free data.
```

So my question is: Why can't we just free the node, like this?:

```c
s_list *node = *begin_list)
free(node)
```

Why does the task provide a function to specifically free data?
My guess would be that if I only free the node the data would still be in stored Memory but wouldn't that mean next needs to be freed aswell?

Also I don't know what a free_fct function could look like. If data would be string, how would a  free_fct function look like?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing how you allocated your memory (maybe show the functions that you use in order to allocate memory). BUT shouldn't you free the data and the note (it's based on the assumption that you allocate A. for data and B. for your NODE)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is to make the list more generic. If you just free the `data` pointer in your remove_node function, you basically can only store pointers to memory allocated by malloc, calloc and realloc in the data pointer.
Furthermore, consider `data` field of a node points to an instance of following struct:

```
struct some_struct{
    FILE *file;
    int *intArray;
}
```

That struct might have been dynamically allocated with `malloc`, so you can free it with `free`. But `file` may contain a valid filehandle, and `intArray` may be a pointer to a dynamically allocated int array. By just freeing `data`, you would create a ressource leak in this case.
However, if your list implementation allows you to pass a "destructor" function, you can pass a function like:

```
void SomeStructDestructor(void* data){
    struct some_struct *temp = (struct some_struct*)data;
    close(temp->file);
    free(temp->intArray);
    free(data);
}
```